# Локализация даты и дней недели в wordpress

Tags: wordpress, дата, локализация

С помощью кода вывел в карточке товара ближайшую дату доставки, но дата и день недели выводится на английском языке, как сделать чтобы было на русском? Магазин на Woocommerce.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form', 'bbloomer_dispatch_info_single_product' );
   
function bbloomer_dispatch_info_single_product() {
    date_default_timezone_set( 'Europe/London' );  
    
    // if FRI/SAT/SUN delivery will be MON
    if ( date( 'N' ) >= 5 ) {
        $del_day = date( "l jS F", strtotime( "next monday" ) );
        $order_by = "Monday";
    } 
    
    // if MON/THU after 4PM delivery will be TOMORROW
    elseif ( date( 'H' ) >= 16 ) {
        $del_day = date( "l jS F", strtotime( "tomorrow" ) );
        $order_by = "tomorrow";
    } 
    
    // if MON/THU before 4PM delivery will be TODAY
    else {
        $del_day = date( "l jS F", strtotime( "today" ) );
        $order_by = "today";
    }

    $html = "<br><div class='woocommerce-message' style='clear:both'>Order by 4PM {$order_by} for delivery on {$del_day}</div>";
    
    echo $html;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: И ВП и WC локализованы на 100%. Переводи тему.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. 
Вот что пишут в комментариях  на сайте автора кода:

Фрагмент этот фантастический, но больно, он не работает для Испании, потому что его нельзя перевести.
Вы можете посмотреть здесь:

Для форматирования дат на других языках необходимо использовать функции setlocale() и strftime() вместо date().

Привет Родольфо !!

Comment: Я этот набор слов не разобрал. Да и не зачем он. Я выше всё сказал. Могу только добавить - не сможешь перевести тему (найти нужные маны) - меняй на нормальную.